# python convention for functions that require different variables depending in which if-elif criteria they satisfy

Tags: python, function, arguments, keyword-argument

I have a function to calculate an engineering parameter via a few different methods.

Is there a better approach than any of the below?

*Input variables:*

User will have supplied either these 4 arguments:

```
option = 1
strength = 10 
gradient = 2 
depth = 5
```

Or these 3 arguments:

```
option = 2
factor = 9
alpha = 2.3
```

**Approach 1**

```
def func1(option, *args):
    if option==1:
        return args[0] + args[1] * args[2]
    elif option==2:
        return args[0] * args[1]
```

Called with either:

```
func1(option, strength, gradient, depth) # if option = 1
func1(option, factor, alpha) # if option = 2
```

- Pros: Function call does not require duplicating names
- Cons: What function is doing is unclear unless you match up with the function call

**Approach 2**

```
def func2(option, **kwargs):
    if option==1:
        return kwargs['strength'] + kwargs['gradient'] * kwargs['depth']
    elif option==2:
        return kwargs['factor'] * kwargs['alpha']
```

Called with either:

```
func2(option=option, strength=strength, gradient=gradient, depth=depth) # option=1
func2(option=option, factor=factor, alpha=alpha) # option=2
```

- Pros: What function is doing is clear from function alone, albeit a bit clunky
- Cons: Cumbersome function call as names are duplicated, especially for more complex functions

**Approach 3**

```
def func3(option, **kwargs):
    if option==1:
        return strength + gradient * depth
    elif option==2:
        return factor * alpha
```

Called with:

```
dict1 = {'option': 1, 'strength': 10, 'gradient': 2, 'depth': 5}
# alternatively the user may have supplied:
dict1 = {'option': 2, 'factor': 9, 'alpha': 2.3}

func3(**dict1)
```

- Pros: What function is doing is clear from function alone. Call is simple & flexible.
- Cons: Must view the dictionary to be sure what variables the function call is passing.

Comment: In all three cases, you are simply writing a wrapper around what should be separate functions. Is there any reason not to simply make the caller responsible for calling the correct function, instead of passing some opaque identifier as an argument to the wrapper?

Comment: Yes, the user will have selected the option value (1 or 2) in an excel input file. So this option value must be used in the script to call the correct equation. If I don't do it as I have done, then I will need to use additional if-elif statements outside the 2 functions, which doesn't seem any better.

Comment: One, each of the two separate functions becomes simpler, as they focus on *one* job. Two, it's clearer to the reader what each function does, as you aren't 
"hiding" the purpose of the option inside the wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should try to make 2 distinct functions with self-descriptive names & call the function according to need. All your current iterations are opaque about how is first argument working and the next people reading this code will have to make logical connections themselves.

However, assuming that is not possible in your problem case, you should go with `Approach 3` and use [`assert`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/assert-statement) to make sure dictionaries passed consists of the keys it needs (with appropriate value constraints as per need).

Comment: Don't use `assert`; its purpose is for debugging and it can be turned off at runtime. Be explicit and check the value of option, raising a `ValueError` if it's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with a variation on Approach 1.
The way I've done this type of thing in the past is making a function map, with the keys being your options:

```py
def func1(strength, gradient, depth):
    return strength + gradient * depth

def func2(factor, alpha):
    return factor * alpha

func_map = {1: func1, 2: func2}


func_map[1](strength, gradient, depth)
func_map[2](factor, alpha)
```

It makes it explicit what the functions are doing, and makes unit testing easy. You could also throw in kwargs in there if you feel strongly about making it easy to call without knowing what arguments go into what function, although you lose some traceability in that approach:

```py
def func1(strength, gradient, depth, **kwargs):
    return strength + gradient * depth

def func2(factor, alpha, **kwargs):
    return factor * alpha

func_map = {1: func1, 2: func2}

args = {strength: 1, gradient: 2, depth: 3, factor: 4, alpha: 5}
func_map[1](**args)
func_map[2](**args)
```

Comment: I've edited the question to make clear that the option value (1 or 2) is pre-selected by the user when all other parameters are selected. Hence, using this function map approach would just displace the problem into requiring if-elif statements to choose which function to call. It seems better to contain all options within same function since both options are calculating the same output parameter (but using different methods).

Comment: not quite sure I follow, seems like you'd just pass it func_map[option](**args) in the latter example, but sounds like I'm missing something specific to your workflow. otherwise your option 2 seems reasonable to me. I just get a bit squeemish about functions with varying variables as it gets to be a mess when there are different options with a different code path within the same function. but in limited circumstances it can be fine.